# Can I setup an Android 7 box play all movis in a usb drive upon start and infinite loop through them?

Tags: media-player

I bought an Android 7.1 box and I like to use it for a marketing event.

The idea is to have a few mp4 files in a usb drive and setup the android box such that it infinitely loops through all the movies in the USB drive upon start.

Is that possible?

Can I add a few images to the loop as well?